# Multiple number from EditText with assigned number Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get number which user inputs and multiple it with some assigned value. I can't see where I've made mistake, my app keeps crashing. I can't even run it.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    Button calculateBtn;
    EditText userEcts;
    TextView summary;
    int price = 200;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        userEcts = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ects_input);
        summary = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_summary);

        calculateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
        calculateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //When the button is clicked, call the calculate method.
                calculate();
            }
        });
    }

    public void calculate() {
        //gets entered text from the EditText,and convert to integers.
        Double ects = Double.parseDouble(userEcts.getText().toString());
        //do the calculation
        Double calculatedPrice = ects * price;
        //set the value to the TextView, to display on screen.
        summary.setText("Ukupno za platit: " + Double.toString(calculatedPrice) + "kn");
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the error log

Comment: what is the error??

Comment: Can you include your crash log??

Comment: Here's the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NyoY.png

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing OnItemSelectedListener

```
change OnItemSelectedListener to View.OnClickListener
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do this :

```
summary.setText("Ukupno za platit: " + calculatedPrice + "kn");
```

String + Double = String

Answer (score 0):

I personally would suggest you to put a check like this on the calculate method before parsing the a string as double as an empty string can cause a crash too while parsing it:

```
  public void calculate() {
        //Put this empty check to prevent crash while parsing empty string.
      if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(userEcts.getText.toString())){
          Double ects = Double.parseDouble(userEcts.getText().toString());
          //do the calculation
          Double calculatedPrice = ects * price;
          //set the value to the TextView, to display on screen.
          summary.setText("Ukupno za platit: " + Double.toString(calculatedPrice) + "kn");
      }

    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've done it all as you answered, but still app keeps crashing on the running the app ... Here's the picture of catlog: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NyoY.png

Answer (score 0):

It works now... on the existing code I've added this code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    calculate();
}
```

Thanks anyway :)